# how to implement a action bar like facebook, by removing header from tab header

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I have implemented action bar and ab Layout with Swipeable Views. I have put a image to each title in the tabs and title. when i am changing the tab, actionbar respectively shows the tab title name in the actionbar. now I want to leave the title only from the tab header, and leave actionbar title and image on the tab header. so it will be looks like facebook app

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_pizza));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_noodle));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_slides));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab4").setTabListener(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_promotion));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab5").setTabListener(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_profile));
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        // set background for action bar tab
        bar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
                .parseColor("#ffffff")));
        bar.show();


@Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        getActionBar().setTitle(tab.getText());
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
```

[image]